# What is the best way to spawn and setup test environments (Amazon EC2) with Jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, continuous-integration, chef-infra

I'm trying to automate test environment creation process. I use Jenkins as my CI server and want to be able to spawn new VM instances (based on predefined template) on the AmazonEC2. I know that there is a plugin for it if you want to use VM as jenkins build slaves. But I want to use VM as ready-to-use test environments where build artifacts will be deployed. So the question is what will be the best approach? I'm currently thinking of using Chef to configure fresh VM instances, but how to spawn the VM itself is a mystery. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want something like [Test-Kitchen](https://github.com/test-kitchen/test-kitchen). You can use Chef and kitchen-ec2 to spin up a machine, run recipe code, and then run some tests on it (usually serverspec or bats, but there are many test drivers). You would run test-kitchen from the Jenkins host itself, so Jenkins doesn't need to worry about making new instances.

Answer (score 1):

Ansible has a good support for Amazon EC2 instance creation etc. Refer [this link](http://docs.ansible.com/ec2_module.html) for more details. You can also use ansible to completely automate your application deployment as well once the EC2 instance is created.

Answer (score 0):

Look into Ansible for automating your deployments.  What we do is have Ansible provision new vm's and then use chef/puppet to config manage the actual environment codebase.  It works wonderfully!

Here's an example playbook architecture:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: True
  roles:
     - load_balancer
     - cloud_servers

- hosts: infra
  gather_facts: True 
  roles: 
     - deploy

- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: True
  roles:
     - test
     - clean_up
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vagrant to spawn the VM via Vagrant plugin on Jenkins. https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Vagrant-plugin

Vagrant is a kind of virtualization wrapper (for wmare, virtualbox,lxc) that permits you to set up config for your VM and to choose between several options:

- Provisionner : Ansible, Chef...
- Synced folder between host and guest
- Network options...

https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/